# Sequence of sines

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis, trigonometry

There is a product of sines, given as  $$\prod_{n=1}^{N} \sin ((an-b)\pi)$$
and the purpose is to transform it into a sum. Using a product-to-sum approach we could multiply componentwise as $$\sin((a-b)\pi)\sin((2a-b)\pi)\sin((3a-b)\pi)...\sin((Na-b)\pi).$$
My question is as follows: is it possible to get a sum as
$\sum_{n=1}^{K}\sin(\pi f(x))$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{K}\cos(\pi f(x))$, where f(x) is a function, which natural points are equivalent to the expression within a trigonometric function after componentwise transformation? So pracctically I want to get a closed formula of the function or a sequence f(x).
Is there maybe another way to calculate the product?

Comment: Fourier series theory will grant you one such formula; however you may need $K\to \infty$ in the expression $\sum_{n=1}^K \sin(\pi f_n(x))$ or the analogous expression for cosines. You can even know whether it will be a series of sines or cosines depending on the parity of the original expression, which can be deduced from the signs of $na-b$ and $N$.

Comment: I am confused by your phrasing. You talk about using the product to sum formula, but instead of doing so, you just apply the definition of the $\prod$ notation to write out the same product without using it. There is no sum involved, so surely you cannot think that definition is a "product-to-sum" formula. You can use this (which is called a "product-to-sum" formula) to accomplish what you want: $$\sin \theta \sin\phi = \dfrac{\cos(\theta - \phi) - \cos(\theta + \phi)}2$$ It will give you a multiplier of $\frac 1{2^K}$, but it should be clear that this is unavoidable.